# Redirect null fetch request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, fetch

A value is passed through a search bar on the webpage, which is appended to a URL and used to fetch JSON data. It works fine however if a value is imputed that the API doesn't have data for a `null` will be returned.

How do I check if the data is null and redirect it before its fetched by my webpage.

**api.js**

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = (app) => {

        let ticker;

        app.post('/search-ticker', (req, res) => {

                ticker = req.body.ticker;

                if(!ticker || ticker.length > 5) {
                        res.redirect('/error');
                } else {
                    res.redirect('/stock-data');
                }

        })

        app.get('/search-ticker-data', (req, res) => {

                const baseurl = 'https://api.twelvedata.com/time_series?symbol=';
                const apiid = '&interval=1day&outputsize=1000&apikey=XXX';

                const stockurl = (url1, url2, ticker) => {

                    let newurl = url1 + ticker + url2;
                    return newurl;
                };

                const stocklink = stockurl(baseurl, apiid, ticker);

                fetch(stocklink)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    res.send({ data });
                }) 
                .catch(err => {
                    res.redirect('/error')
                });

                }                

        })

}
```

**NULL JSON DATA**

```
Object
 data:
  data: null
  message: "There is an error in the query. Please check your query and try again."
  status: "error"
```

Comment: If I understand your question, then it isn't quite possible. You're asking "how can I do a request, then if the response is null not do the request in the first place". But that's not possible, you have to do a request in the first place to see if it's null. But that's a perfectly fine flow, do the request, then if it's null, return that to the webpage and redirect accordingly

Comment: The webpage has a `fetch('/search-ticker-data')` to grab the data. But if its null I'm not sure how to redirect it in my component class. I was hoping to do it in the backend before its called by the page.

Comment: '/search-ticker-data' endpoint returns promise, so in client(React Component) inside then method you can check if(response) this.props.history.push('loc1')}else{this.props.history.push('loc2').

Comment: @Pranay I'm new to this could you explain a bit more. What is props.history?

Comment: If you are using react-router and loading your components than whenever the components are loaded there will be history property set on "props". When you run this.props.history.push("loc1") command, your component "loc1" will be loaded. Ofcourse this is one way of navigation, other ways like Redirect are also available

Comment: Yes I am using react-router. Will look into this right now. Thanks for your comment! Can't vote up sorry :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just  check if data is null inside your `.then()`

```
fetch(stocklink)
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(data => {

   //check if data is null
   if (data && !data.data) {

      res.redirect('/error');
      return;
   }

   res.send({ data });
 }) 
 .catch(err => {
   res.redirect('/error')
 });
```

Comment: Looks promising. See my edit for the null data JSON. `(!data)` didn't work. I tried `(data.data == null)` and it failed to redirect as well. Am I close? Thanks

Comment: Ok this works. Only thing is my webpage still throws an error due to trying to format null data even though this redirects to `/error`. Any way to cancel the route or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  axios to make a request and store the response in a variable and check if it is null or not. If null do something else do other thing. 
Usage:

```
`
var res = await axios.get("url");
let data = res.data;
if(data !== null)
    //do something
else 
    //do something
`
```

Comment: Never tried axios. Can I put this in my componentDidMount? If so, how can I send the url over? Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: why use ```axios``` instead of ```fetch```?

Comment: Axios has certain advantages over fetch like better error handling  in case of 400 responses and you don't need to use res.json() to get the required response data, in case of axios it does it for you.